# How to do operations like copy, rename, delete on multiple files in NERDTree vim?

Tags: multiple-files

Is there any way to do this for multiple files in NERDTree? Something similar along the lines of vifm. From the **m** menu I see that it is only possible for one file at a time.

Comment: If the plugin's doc doesn't mention a way to do it, it is unlikely that it exists. I think you'll have a more definitive answer if you use the plugin [issue tracker](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/issues)

Comment: Worst case scenerio, temporarily open a netrw buffer and use `:help netrw-mf` for this. I'd be surprised if NERDTree doesn't offer similar functionality, but I didn't see it in a brief skim of the doc file on Github.